# nvD3 : want to Create a DualAxisBarChart using NVD3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to create a `DualAxisBarchart` but kind of stuck. Tried many way but actually am able to create Two `yAxis` but instead to create two separate bar its creating two bar at the same place please suggest me some approach am creating this using `multichart()` function

Comment: Post your code in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4ohxfLaepnOnApDCVQK?p=preview) or Fiddle and it may help us find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used nvd3, however I have created a dual axis bar chart using d3. In the code below I am assuming the variable height, x, svg are already defined. The only differences are the ranges for the upperY and lowerY functions and how the lowerBars y and height are defined. I really hope this helps

```
var upperY = d3.scale.linear().range([height / 2, 0]);
var lowerY = d3.scale.linear().range([height / 2, height]);

var upperYAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(upperY)
    .orient("left");

var lowerYAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(lowerY)
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(upperYAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y2 axis")
    .call(lowerYAxis);

var upperBars = svg.selectAll(".upperBar")
    .data(upperBarData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "upperBar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.index); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return upperY(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height / 2 - upperY(d.value); });

var lowerBars = svg.selectAll(".lowerBar")
    .data(lowerBarData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "lowerBar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.index); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height / 2; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return lowerY(d.value) - height / 2; });
```

Comment: johnnty thanx for this solution. i can use this for my other issue where my small values bars hiding behind the big ones.. but again am saying what i want to create two bars on xAxis with two yAxis check githubnvd3 issue no #973  https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues

Comment: Sorry Vikas, I thought you meant creating a upper bar chart and a lower one. From your issue am I correct in thinking that you want a y axis on the left and a y axis on the right and one set of bars to use left axis and another to use the right?

Comment: So I tried out something. If you are using rangeRoundBands and `x.rangeBand()` for the width then try setting one set of bars width to `x.rangeBand() / 2`. Then set the other bars x to `x(d.index) + x.rangeBand() / 2` and its width to `x.rangeBand() / 2`